# Slot context not taken

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Context not found...

```js
Vue.component("custom-table", {
    name: 'CustomTable',
    template: "#custom-table",
    created: function() {
      console.log('Created', this.rows);
    },
    mounted: function() {
      console.log('Mounted', this.rows);
    },
    data: function() {
    },
    props: {
        rows: Array
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="custom-table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <slot name="head"></slot>
        </thead>
        <tbody slot name="body">
        </tbody>
    </table
</script>


<custom-table :rows="myRows">
  <thead slot="head">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody v-for="it in myRows">
    <tr slot="body">
      <td>{{ it.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ it.ange }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</custom-table>
```

I received this error ..

> Property or method "it" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
>   (found in root instance)

And `myRows` is

```
[
  { name: 'Name1', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Name2', age: 30 }
]
```

Comment: maybe instead of `myRows` it should be just `rows` in v-for

Comment: I tried too.. same error

Comment: See the [documentation on scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).  You need to configure your slot to accept properties being passed to it.  I've never done that with raw javascript -- just with [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) so I'm not sure how to do it in your sample but the scoped slots documentation should get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't use the thead and tbody elements outside table - in parsing process browser will 'fix' code as yours :) It is well known, documented caveat, btw. So, improve your code. I am using custom table this way:

```js
Vue.component("custom-table", {
  name: 'CustomTable',
  template: "#custom-table",
  props: {
    cols: Array,
    rows: Array
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myRows: [
      {name: 'Name1', age: 20},
      {name: 'Name2', age: 30}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <custom-table
    :cols="['Name', 'Age']"
    :rows="myRows"
  ></custom-table>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="custom-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="col in cols">{{ col }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="it in rows">
        <td>{{ it.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ it.age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```